# Bitcoin qt client opening and immediately closing

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm trying to run a bitcoin-qt client (to sync blockchain) on a raspberryPi (using Raspbian Stretch With Desktop). However, the bitcoin-qt client opens and just closes. BTW db.log is empty. Here is (tail) of my debug.log (in which atl i don't spot any errors).

```
2018-07-18 16:31:09 Bitcoin version v0.13.1.0-g03422e5
2018-07-18 16:31:09 InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Default data directory /home/pi/.bitcoin
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using data directory /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using config file /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using at most 125 connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using 4 threads for script verification
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September  9, 2013)
2018-07-18 16:31:10 scheduler thread start
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using wallet wallet.dat
2018-07-18 16:31:10 init message: Verifying wallet...
2018-07-18 16:31:10 CDBEnv::Open: LogDir=/mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/db.log
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Bound to [::]:8333
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Bound to 0.0.0.0:8333
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Cache configuration:
2018-07-18 16:31:10 * Using 2.0MiB for block index database
2018-07-18 16:31:10 * Using 8.0MiB for chain state database
2018-07-18 16:31:10 * Using 290.0MiB for in-memory UTXO set
2018-07-18 16:31:10 init message: Loading block index...
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Opening LevelDB in /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using obfuscation key for /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Opening LevelDB in /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/chainstate
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Opened LevelDB successfully
2018-07-18 16:31:10 Using obfuscation key for /mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/chainstate: 68657831113e179
```

Any idea what might be going on. My next solution is to simply delete the .bitcoin directory and start afresh.

[EDIT]
I think its important to mention that it did startup once and it was synching. Then for some reason my pi shutdown so i coudln't close it in a graceful way i guess. That could be the issue. In anycase, wanted to know if there was a way to start synching from where i left off.

Comment: Looks alright. Does `/mnt/usbstorage/.bitcoin/db.log` have any errors?

Comment: The db.log is empty.

Comment: How did you install bitcoin-qt on a raspberry pi? AFAIK, there is no bitcoin-qt binary for ARM devices yet.

Comment: Well, i just used apt-get to download bitcoin-qt and bitcoind and ran bitcoin-qt.

Comment: Try running it from a terminal so you can see any messages generated; in particular, if it's getting a signal, you'll see a message.  Also check your system logs (maybe `/var/log/syslog`).  How much RAM does this device have, and how much swap if any?

Comment: Also, v0.13.1 is very old, and I don't think you'll be able to use it successfully with the current network.  So you're eventually going to have to find or compile a more recent binary.

Comment: Good point @NateEldredge , i will try to find a newer version and probably restart the whole process. Thanks.

Comment: Note that if you don't have at least 2 GB of RAM, it's probably a lost cause.

Comment: I believe default is 1GB. I have not added any more. Do you think that will be an issue?